# Simple translation for one of my Anki cards, why is 上り translated to going "downtown"?

Tags: grammar, translation, words

So I THOUGHT I understood the meaning, but the sentence translation threw me off.
Wouldn't it technically be UPtown since the train is going up? If not, can someone explain why it's set up this way? I might have misunderstood. Thanks in advance!![image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

上り used like this means the train is going to a major location, just like English "[*up*-train](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rail_directions#Up_and_down)" does. However, English "downtown" happens to refer to a major location in a city. Therefore, in **English** practice, a train can be *up* when it goes to a *downtown*. This is not a problem in Japanese.

Comment: Okay, I see what you're saying. Is there an opposite that's equivalent to it? As in NOT heading in a downtown direction? I guess I was thinking about it from a New Yorker point of view. Uptown train takes you north while downtown trains take you south.

Comment: @Cruzible A 下り電車 is a train from a major/central location (it can be going north, south or whatever). Please read the "in Japan" part of the Wikipedia link.

Comment: I failed to see there was a section in Japan, thank you so much. Good to know this information!